# Input fields don't get the correct values from a data-default attribute

Tags: jquery

I have some table rows with input fields; for each field I set a data-default attribute: in case of input change, I have a way to go back to default value picking the data-default value

For each row I also have a checkbox: if checked, fields value go to '0:00' (it's a "hour:minutes" format); if unchecked, values should go back to default

Here comes the problem: when unchecked, the input fields DON'T switch to default value, but get empty. This is my code:

```
$('.cb').click(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var parent = el.closest('tr');
    if (el.is(':checked')) {
        parent.find('.timepicker').val('0:00');
    } else {        
        parent.find('.timepicker').val($(this).data('default'));
    }
});
```

And here's the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w17ffqxy/

Please, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('.cb').click(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    var parent = el.closest('tr');
    if (el.is(':checked')) {
        parent.find('.timepicker').val('0:00');
    } else {        
        parent.find('.timepicker').each(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).attr('data-default'));
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w17ffqxy/2/).

Comment: In all fairness this was the first completely correct answer. I thank Beginner for his alerting me to my mistake

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are attempting to access `data('default')` on the checkbox itself when it doesnt have that attribute. You need to access the `.timepicker` like

```
parent.find('.timepicker').val(function() {
        return $(this).data('default');
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w17ffqxy/5/)

Comment: @Beginner, it is working. Make sure you are checking the correct fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w17ffqxy/1/

Comment: Check again. it is defaulting to first field's value. If you don't loop then it will  assign the value of the first element

Comment: @Beginner, thanks for your awesome sportmanship and correction! Ive corrected my answer

Comment: Thanks, but unchecking the checkbox sets all fields to 9:00, not to their default values

Comment: @Ivan, I had corrected my answer. You can see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/w17ffqxy/5/